# How do i get a full url inside a class that extends AbstractHelper using magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I have a class that extends AbstractHelper

In this class i make a curl call to an external site. In the payload i need to provide a link to a static css file that resides in my extensions directory.

Experimenting, i have been able to get the required URL in an view->frontend-->templates->index.phtml

```
<?php
    $xioDefault = $this->getViewFileUrl("xio_OnlinePayment::css/xioDefault.css");
    error_log("(".__LINE__.")".__METHOD__."$xioDefault\n");
?>
```

the URL i see is something like

http://localhost/static/version1651243933/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/xio_OnlinePayment/css/xioDefault.css

What i can not figure out (magento noob), is how to get this same URL in my class that extends AbstractHelper that i then can pass to my curl payload.

getViewFileUrl is not something that available in AbstractHelper

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to inject `\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository` into your class and experiment with the `getUrl` function. This is built to retrieve static view file URLs:

```
/**
     * Getter for static view file URL
     *
     * @param string $fileId
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl($fileId)
    {
        $asset = $this->createAsset($fileId);
        return $asset->getUrl();
    }
```

You can see an example of Magento core using this in `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product::getImageUrl`, where this class is injected and instantiated in a property called `_assetRepo`:

```
public function getImageUrl($product)
    {
        ...
            $url = $this->_assetRepo->getUrl('Magento_Catalog::images/product/placeholder/image.jpg');
        ...
        return $url;
    }
```